# Alternative definition of Legendre transform as an integral

Tags: integration, convex-analysis, linear-transformations, transformation

Let $f(x)$ be a convex function. Define $g(y)$ via the integral:

$$\mathrm{e}^{-g(y)} =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{e}^{yx-f(x)}$$

assuming that the integral converges. The domain of $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ is the entire real line.

**Is $g(y)$ the Legendre transform of $f(x)$?**

Some context. I found this formula reading a paper, Eq. 13, http://stacks.iop.org/1742-5468/2011/i=03/a=P03008. There it is claimed that an integration of this form yields the Legendre transform. My question is whether this formula can be used in general as an equivalent definition of the Legendre transform (for the standard definition, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation).

Comment: It's clearly related to the Legendre transform, but I can't see any way to transform it into an ordinary Legendre transform. It's closer to a [two-sided Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform).

Comment: @md2perpe Maybe it is *not* a Legendre transform in general. A counterexample would also answer my question.

Comment: It's quite clear to me that it is not the Legendre transform as it stands. But it could be $T^{-1} \circ \mathcal J \circ T$ for some simple transform $T$, where $\mathcal J$ is the Legendre transform. But I cannot see any possibility for that either.

Comment: How do you know it is not the Legendre transform? Can you come up with a counter example? Or explain your argument please?

Comment: Should there perhaps be a minus sign instead of a plus sign in the exponent inside the integral? If not, I cannot see that the integral would even be defined for a convex function $f$. Can a function be convex and tend to $-\infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, you are correct. In the paper they use *minus* the Legendre transform, but they never mention it explicitly! But you are right, thanks. I corrected the question.

Comment: If $f(x) = ax^2$ for some $a>0$ then we can easily evaluate the integral. Let's do the case $a=\frac12$. First we have
$$yx-f(x) = yx - \frac12 x^2 = - \frac12 (x^2-2yx) = - \frac12 \left( (x-y)^2 + y^2 \right)$$
This gives
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \frac12 \left( (x-y)^2 + y^2 \right)} \, dx
= \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- \frac12 (x-y)^2 } \, dx \right) e^{-\frac12 y^2} = \sqrt{2\pi} e^{-\frac12 y^2}$$
so
$$g(y) = \frac12 \ln(2\pi) - \frac12 y^2$$
In this particular case we almost have the Legendre transformation.

Comment: @md2perpe Maybe we need a constant factor. Also, recall that the Legendre transform is defined up to an additive constant.

Comment: The Legendre transform $f^*$ is *not* defined up to an additive constant. It's defined by
$$f^*(x^*) = \sup_x (xx^* - f(x))$$
However, it satisfies $(f^*)' \circ f' = f' \circ (f^*)' = \mathrm{id}$ and is up to a constant uniquely defined by this.

Comment: @md2perpe I was thinking of the 2nd definition.

Comment: Also, I think that it should be
$$\mathrm{e}^{-g(y)} =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{e}^{yx-f(x)}$$
i.e. with a minus sign before $g(y)$ in the left hand side.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, you are right again.